# Android Studio 1.4 Rendering Problems NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors

Tags: java, android

Rendering Problems 
**NOTE:** This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.
The following classes could not be found:

```
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

I am using Android Studio 1.4

Problems here:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

if you used sdk 28

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

you change it to 27 , that means :

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

and in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

....
this way solved my problem!
happy code!

Answer (score 1):

To use the class `ActionBarOverlayLayout` you need to include this in the dependencies section :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

Sync the project once again and then you will find no problem

Answer (score 1):

1. See which **Android SDK Build-tools** version you Installed from
   **Android SDK Manager.**
2. Use this version in **buildToolsVersion** inside **build.gradle** and remember that **targetSdkVersion** must be same.
3. After that add this library, Remember that **23.0.1** is my downloaded version. I use **targetSdkVersion 25** and **buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"**.

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
>
> compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

Now from File menu **Invalidate cached/Restart** you project. And one more thing in XML preview must select your download version.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File>Invalidate catches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the design library into your project? It looks like you're missing a reference in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following if you have done all of the below then you shouls be able to compile and build your project.

```
1) Is your Activity extending AppCompactActivity
2) Is your Theme extending Theme.AppCompat.Light or its subclass
3) Have you imported these to your build.gradle
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1 or add them as jar if you are using eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had these issues with the Android Studio designer in 1.4.
I uninstalled it and went back to 1.3.2, this version seems to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and i've looked everywhere for answers and none could help me fix this bug. and my final solution is to reinstall android studio 1.3.2 and it worked just fine.

For Windows:
IDE + SDK bundle: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.3.2.0/android-studio-bundle-141.2178183-windows.exe (1.1 GB)

For Mac:
DMG: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.3.2.0/android-studio-ide-141.2178183-mac.dmg (351 MB)

Answer (score 0):

Well i also face this problem so i **Clean** my project but still the error occur then i close **Android Studio**. And then again open it. and the error gone. this method solved my problem 
**here is my gradle file**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.apps.myproject"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'}
```